# How to match a word that doesn't start with X but ends with Y with regex

Tags: python, regex

Example;

```
X=This
Y=That
```

**not matching;**

```
ThisWordShouldNotMatchThat
ThisWordShouldNotMatch
WordShouldNotMatch
```

**matching;**

```
AWordShouldMatchThat
```

I tried `(?<!...)` but seems not to be easy :)

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: Do you mean word like a sequence of letters?

Comment: @mcandre I am using python but this is not a complex one to be different much I guess
@Gumbo it is actually a word which could be matched with \w+

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
^(?!This).*That$
```

As a free-spacing regex:

```
^             # Start of string
  (?!This)    # Assert that "This" can't be matched here
  .*          # Match the rest of the string
  That        # making sure we match "That"
$             # right at the end of the string
```

This will match a single word that fulfills your criteria, but only if this word is the only input to the regex. If you need to find words inside a string of many other words, then use

```
\b(?!This)\w*That\b
```

`\b` is the word boundary anchor, so it matches at the start and at the end of a word. `\w` means "alphanumeric character. If you also want to allow non-alphanumerics as part of your "word", then use `\S` instead - this will match anything that's not a space.

In Python, you could do `words = re.findall(r"\b(?!This)\w*That\b", text)`.

Comment: I appreciate your honest critique with no smart ass comments. I of course am bowing out now.

Comment: @ChaosPandion, I suggest you undelete your answer and modify the regex to use lookahead and lookbehind - I find it rather elegant and would upvote it immediately. It might even be faster than mine because the regex engine doesn't have to do any backtracking. The only disadvantage I can think of is that it wouldn't work in JavaScript or Ruby 1.8 because those don't support lookbehind.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think one point missed here is -word- not a sequence of letters here is the test http://regexr.com?2rka3

Comment: The regex works fine when applied to individual words. In your test, the words are sprinkled across lines with more other words in between. You could have put this in the specification.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker that's right so it is good point for me to learn if words are individual or among others makes a big difference, thanks again...